# Cannot fetch URL using an ajax call, but can via Postman

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Not sure why I can't I fetch the url "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/1rQX6kg84TqcwGtZHYIdn4/album" using `$.get`, but when I paste the exact same url into postman, it worked.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u5me8csx/)

```
$.get(
    "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/1rQX6kg84TqcwGtZHYIdn4/album",
    function (data, status) {
        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    }
);
```

Comment: I get error 404 for that URL

Comment: @JaromandaX I'm able to get the response using postman

Comment: it could be an issue with CORS support...

Comment: Improved the title and code readability

Comment: Giving 404 in postman too; as per @elssar please check that `Do you have any spotity API tokens in your postman environment/globals/saved request?`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any spotity API tokens in your postman environment/globals/saved request? I'm guessing that the API requires an API token to be send (usually in the header), which is happening in Postman, but you aren't doing that in your ajax call.

Postman has a generate code feature that will generate code snippets for a particular request, and JQuery ajax is one of the supported targets. Why don't you try generating a snippet from Postman and see if there is a difference?